# I want to stay on logout page, when application runs again (if user did not hit logout button)

Tags: objective-c

**Below is my code till sign in process**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "LogOutViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *userid = [defaults objectForKey:@"uid"];
    NSString *password = [defaults objectForKey:@"pswrd"];

   _lbluserid.text = userid;
   _lblpswrd.text = password;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)btnsignin:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setObject:_lbluserid.text forKey:@"uid"];
    [defaults setObject: _lblpswrd.text forKey:@"pswrd"];

    [defaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"Credentials are saved");

    LogOutViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"logoutvc"];
    controller.getUserid = _lbluserid.text;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
@end
```

**I have another view which will appear by signing in, on that view I have Log Out button, Now what I want is if user didn't hit logout button the same page (log out page) will be displayed when I run my app again.**

Please help me..

Comment: you can simply make your logOut controller as root controller and your app start from that controller. You dont have to do anything else!

Comment: Thanksfor your suggestion Teja.. but I dont want LogOut controller as my root controller in all cases, I want it only if user did not hits LogOut button.  If user logout from account I want my sigin page as a root controller. can you please help me?

Comment: ohh you mean you want to say in main controller all the time until user signed out ? THe name log out controller is bit confusing!

Comment: @TejaNandamuri    When app runs I want to stay on LogOutViewController (it's my 2nd view controller which will appear by clicking signin button [on my main controller]) until user hits logout button..once user hits and I runs app again then I want my main controller as a rootvc

Comment: you can check if the password is saved or not in your first controller, if yes, then push to second one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try amend you code to.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "LogOutViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *userid = [defaults objectForKey:@"uid"];
    NSString *password = [defaults objectForKey:@"pswrd"];

    _lbluserid.text = userid;
    _lblpswrd.text = password;

    if([defaults boolForKey:@"logedIn"]){
         [self moveToLogoutViewController];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)btnsignin:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setObject:_lbluserid.text forKey:@"uid"];
    [defaults setObject: _lblpswrd.text forKey:@"pswrd"];
    [defaults setBool: YES forKey:@"logedIn"];

    [defaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"Credentials are saved");
    [self moveToLogoutViewController];

}
- (void) moveToLogoutViewController{
    LogOutViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"logoutvc"];
    controller.getUserid = _lbluserid.text;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks a ton....I had tried this one and its working perfectly....thank you once again....!!!! :D

Comment: @JuhiDanak Thank you! And please accept my answer if it solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

First Open AppDelegate class in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Check user is exist or not by using NSUserDefaults.If user exist you can show LogOutViewController

Answer (score 0):

Use keychain to store user credentials. In your viewCOntroller class, in viewDidLoad check if user credentials exist or not.If exist, then call:

```
 LogOutViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"logoutvc"];
controller.getUserid = //get user id from keychain;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```